# How keep groovy/XMLSlurper from stripping html tags from a node?

Tags: grails, groovy, html-parsing, xmlslurper

I'm reading an HTML file from a POST response and parsing it with XMLSlurper. The textarea node on the page has some HTML code put into it (non-urlencoded - not my choice) and when I read that value, Groovy strips all the tags.

Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea><html><body>This has html code for some reason</body></html></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I parse the above and then find(...) the "textarea" node, it returns to me:

```
This has html code for some reason
```

and none of the tags. How do I keep the tags?

Comment: Can you enclose the textarea block in CDATA?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting the right data, but printing it out wrong...  Can you try using StreamingMarkupBuilder to convert the node back to a piece of xml?

```
def xml = '''<html>
            |  <body>
            |    <textarea><html><body>This has html code for some reason</body></html></textarea>
            |  </body>
            |</html>'''

def ta = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).body.textarea

String content = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  mkp.yield ta.children()
}

assert content == '<html><body>This has html code for some reason</body></html>'
```