# groovy findAll expands &lt

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an XML document with embedded HTML tags wrapped by "&lt" and "&gt" (it parses cleanly by `XMLSlurper.parseText()`). When I use Groovy's `depthFirst.findAll()`, the returned list shows the `&lt` and `&gt` replaced by `<` and `>`. This makes it difficult to subsequently search the original XML content, since the list items returned no longer match the characters in the original XML.

Fragment from the XML:

```
<label>Read about it &lt;a href="http://whatever"&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;</label>
```

This code:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def list = root.depthFirst().findAll{ it.name().equalsIgnoreCase('label') }
```

Gives me:

```
Read about it <a href="http://whatever">here</a>
```

Is there a way to prevent sequences such as &lt/&gt from being mangled by methods like findAll?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710164/how-keep-groovy-xmlslurper-from-stripping-html-tags-from-a-node) - it's similar problem. Proposed solution works nicely in your case too:

```
def xml = '<label>Read about it &lt;a href="http://whatever"&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;</label>'

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def list = root.depthFirst().findAll{ it.name().equalsIgnoreCase('label') }

String content = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  mkp.yield list[0].text()
}

assert content == 'Read about it &lt;a href="http://whatever"&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;'
```